# Poco websocket server example

Tags: c++, websocket, poco-libraries

I want to create an application that consists of a web based front-end and a c++ back-end. My choice is to use websocket protocol in order to achieve data transfer between them.Specifically the front end will trigger some measurements that will be done in the back-end and eventually return and store the  relevant values in the front-end. I decided for the websocket protocol implementation to use poco library and specifically I came across the following example https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/samples/WebSocketServer/src/WebSocketServer.cpp. However since I haven't totally grasped the factory concept in C++  I haven't figured out the role of class RequestHandlerFactory.Is it possible for someone to explain what is the role of the aforementioned class and regarding my implementation (**front-end -> trigger back-end -> back-end do measurements ->back-end returns the value to front-end in order to be depicted in a web-based gui**) do I need to make any modifications to make this work for my case ?

Answer (score 0):

As you might have read in the sample, there are two implementations derived from HTTPServer. So depending on the type of connection requested by the client (WebsocketRequest, PageRequest) one can return the appropriate HTTPServer. The work of factory class is to handle the incoming request, decide which class should handle it (depending on the connection requested). 
Since you would be requesting to exchange data and not a request to display a HTML document, you should go for WebSocketRequestHandler. Yes it can be done. You might want to remove the PageRequestHandler since you wouldn't be using it.